# Actual number when cout pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
int x;
int *y;

x=2;
y= &x;
cout << y << endl;
cout << y[0] << endl; #this cout shows the value of x ( 2 at this case)
cout << y[1] << endl;
cout << y[2] << endl;
cout << y[3] << endl;
return 0;
}
```

When I Try to cout only the pointer it comes in ) 0x(hex value), and I was trying to get only the hex value of it, why is that happening?

Comment: C++ have no bounds checking. Going out of bounds (which you do when indexing `y` with anything other than `0`) leads to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: `y[0]` = `*(y + 0)`. Not sure what else were you expecting, though.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: And unrelated to your problem, please read [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: Hex values have the prefix `0x`. It's expected...

Comment: What output do you expect for `cout << y[1]`, `cout << y[2]` and `cout << y[3]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it comes in ) 0x(hex value), and I was trying to get only the hex value of it, why is that happening?

Because that is how the IO streams have been specified to behave.

If you want to get rid of the base prefix, you can achieve that by converting the pointer to an integer and using the `std::noshowbase` manipulator. Integers are shown in decimal base by default though, so if you want the hex value, then use the `std::hex` manipulator.

```
std::cout << std::noshowbase << std::hex << (std::uintptr_t)y << '\n';
```

---

Accessing `y[1]` and other indices greater than 0 cause your program to have undefined behaviour.